# Cache PHP extensions installed with Pecl on CircleCI

Tags: php, pecl, circleci-2.0

We are using CircleCI as build server for php symfony application and we require the mongodb library with composer, which is dependent on the mongodb extension, that we install with pecl. So we have the following steps in our build:

```
- run: sudo pecl install mongodb
- run: echo -e "extension=mongodb.so" | sudo tee /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini > /dev/null
- run: cd app && composer install --no-interaction
```

This works fine, but the PECL mongo db extension takes half of our build time.

Is there a way to store the installed PECL extensions into the CircleCI cache?

I have tried the following:

```
- save_cache: 
          key: pecl-v1-{{ checksum "scripts/pecl-extensions.sh" }}
          paths:
            - /usr/local/20160303/mongodb.so
```

But this doesn't work - mongodb is downloaded again by PECL. What are the directories that I should try to cache in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question. There is a way to cache PHP extensions installed with PECL. One needs to know where exactly the pecl extensions are installed (**pecl config-show**). It seems that on the Circle CI containers this location is:

*/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/*

The extensions can be copied from this folder to a temporary directory which can be cached and restored. Restored files can be copied back with sudo.

```
  - run: pecl config-show 
  - run: mkdir pecl-cache
  - restore_cache:
     keys:
     - pecl-v1-{{ checksum "scripts/pecl-extensions.sh" }}
     - pecl-v1-

  - run:
      name: Copying restored pecl extensions cache into extensions directory 
      command: sudo cp -R pecl-cache/. /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/

  - run: 
      name: Install mongodb pecl extensions if mongodb.so is not there
      command: >
        if [ ! -f /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so ]; then 
            sudo pecl install mongodb ;
        fi

  - run:
      name: Copying pecl extensions to temp directory which will be cached
      command: sudo cp -R /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/* pecl-cache/

  - save_cache: 
      key: pecl-v1-{{ checksum "scripts/pecl-extensions.sh" }}
      paths:
        - pecl-cachedocker-php-ext-install
```